# General solution of the Zero Gaussian Curvature Monge-Ampère Differential Equation

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Suppose we have (but we don't know what it is) a parameterized surface of Monge type $$ \textbf{x}(u,v)=\bigl(u,v,f(u,v)\bigr).$$
The particular Monge-Ampère equation is $$ \boxed{f_{uu} f_{vv}-(f_{uv})^2=0}.$$
I know that the surfaces with $K=0$ verify the equation, like planes, cylinders, ... According to the theory of Differential Equations (Moon and Spencer, 1969; Zwillinger, 1997) this particular Monge-Ampère equation verify:
$$ \text{d}f= f_u \text{d}u + f_v \text{d}v, \quad \text{d}f_u =0, \quad \text{d}f_v=0.$$
What this result does mean? Can I obtain an explicit expression of $\textbf{x}(u,v)$?

Comment: The only solutions are surfaces with $K=0$, and those can be easily classified (if you assume $f$ is real analytic). It's a basic exercise in undergraduate differential geometry to see that any such surface must be (locally) a plane, a cylinder, a cone, or a tangent developable surface. I don't think trying to solve the PDE is going to be very useful.

Comment: Sure, but does that give you the geometric insight?

Comment: @ClareFrancis: I am confused about what you are asking. You already know it is a degenerate case of the Monge-Ampere equation, and you know that the only surfacses of $K = 0$ are classifiable, what more can you be asking for?